# How to change default website for SharePoint Server.?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

I want to change the default launching page for SharePoint website.

for Ex:

currently its launching: **http://server/pages/default.aspx** (when user enters **http://server/**)

I want to change it to--> **http://server/mysite/default.aspx** (when user enters **http://server/**)

Thanks

Comment: FYI - You also may have some luck using ServerFault.com if you can't get any help here

Answer (score 1):

What's the site structure?  Is /mysite a Subsite of a publishing site?  Is it a "personal" site?  Or a "My Site"?

A welcome page (site settings) defines the starting page, you can add a redirect page to something else.

Not really clear on what "rules" for the redirect (or rewrite?) that you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Check out HeliconTech ISAPI_Rewrite, you can easily put a redirect in place that will happen above the ASP.Net layer.